# git rebase - bulk change messages

Tags: git, git-rebase

Is it possible to change the message of one, or multiple commits while being in the interactive rebase mode?

I have to prepend a TaskId to every commit.

Current state:

```
pick 7c2dbd5 Message1
pick d57eb65 Message2
...
pick d57eb65 MessageN
```

Target state

```
pick 7c2dbd5 [TaskID] Message1
pick d57eb65 [TaskID] Message2
...
pick d57eb65 [TaskID] MessageN
```

Ideally, I'd like to perform this operation automatically without leaving the editor.

Comment: In this particular case, I'd run `git rebase` with `EDITOR` or `core.editor` temporarily set to a shell script that does the trick, or perhaps use `git filter-branch` with a message filter that does the same. But [ElpieKay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63812602/1256452) is fine too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pick 7c2dbd5 Message1
x git commit --amend -m "[TaskID] Message1"
pick d57eb65 Message2
x git commit --amend -m "[TaskID] Message2"
...
pick d57eb65 MessageN
x git commit --amend -m "[TaskID] MessageN"
```

`x $command` or `exec $command` runs the command after the previous action is done.